# Force list items in div to float once div height is reached

Tags: css, html, overflow, css-float

I have a div with a fixed height and inside a dynamic unordered list.

Currently the list items overflow the div.
What needs to happen is to float the list items so that they do **not** overflow the div.

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) maybe to make it easier to help you?

Comment: Where do you want them to go?  If there isn't enough space to display all of them, you won't be able to display all of them.  It might be possible to have them overlap or go into columns, but you probably want to specify that behavior if that is what you want to happen.

Comment: Actually just doing another google search brings me to a [jQuery columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/). I need something that doesn't create equal floated lists though. For example: I have 10 items. The container height can hold 8 items high. I want the first float to hold 8 items and the second float to hold the remaining 2. All the columnizers I've seen equal out the contents (4 items + 4 items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use css3 columns:

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draFk/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    background: #00f;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;

  -webkit-column-count: 2;  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
     -moz-column-count: 2;     -moz-column-gap: 15px;
          column-count: 2;          column-gap: 15px;

}
li
{
    background: #ff0;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Wow nice. I had no clue about **column-count** or **column-gap**. I'll give this a shot quick. Do you know off-hand the browser limitations?

Comment: This is exactly what was in the article I sent you Jared :)

Comment: Sorry I don't know at the moment but it'd be easy to find out.

Comment: This is a great method if you don't need out of the box IE support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `overflow` property of the `div` to various values.

You may consider using `hidden` if you simply want the list to cut off, or perhaps `scroll` if you want the user to be able to see the full list.

```
#myDiv{
   overflow:hidden;
   height:200px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ewPHc/2/)

This is assuming that your main criteria is for the list items to not overflow the div. If you wish for the items to stack somehow then there are different methods available to acheive this. The main one is the divide up your li's and float those containers.

There's an article about this on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) on [Multi Column Lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/).

Comment: Check my response above. I'm not looking to hide the contents at all.

Comment: That article is almost 10 years old and uses a nasty hack lol.

Comment: It _is_ an old article but I believe it's all still very relevant. Their first sugestion is to use the CSS3 multi-column module, if this is available for the browsers you're intending to target, it could be just the thing.